# cypher from a group of nodes return nodes within a certain distance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working with users assigned to a specific Taxi. Each user has a Grid destination (drop off) e.g.

```
MATCH (g:Grid)<-[rp:DROP_OFF]-(u:User)-[:ASSIGNED]->(t:Taxi {name:'Taxi1813'})
RETURN g.name as gridName, rp.time as dropTime, u.name as userName
```

This is the result

```
   gridName  dropTime userName
   Grid1347  04:44    User183
   Grid1239  04:38    User177
   Grid811   04:44    User198
   Grid765   04:45    User197
   Grid1184  04:41    User179
   Grid333   04:45    User186
```

I would like to return the users, who are close to each other (friend of friend) and within a certain time.

For that, i need to see if the time between each grid is less than an *n* value. The relationship btwn each grid is e.g.

```
(:Grid)-[:TO {time:3}]-(:Grid)
```

Therefore, from the group of returned Grids, i want to check which of them are close to each other

*is Grid1347 close to G1239?, is G1347 close to G811?... is G1239 close to G1347?... etc..etc*

If i run this query, to get the users and grids in the range [:TO*1..2] that are assigned to the specific *:Taxi*

```
MATCH
  (t:Taxi {name:'Taxi1813'})<-[:ASSIGNED]-(u2:User)-[:DROP_OFF]->
  (g2:Grid)-[:TO*1..2]-(g:Grid)<-[rp:DROP_OFF]-(u:User)-[:ASSIGNED]->
  (t:Taxi {name:'Taxi1813'})
RETURN u.name, g.name, u2.name, g2.name
```

I got this

```
u.name  g.name      u2.name g2.name
User183 Grid1347    User177 Grid1239
User177 Grid1239    User183 Grid1347
User177 Grid1239    User179 Grid1184
User177 Grid1239    User179 Grid1184
User179 Grid1184    User177 Grid1239
User179 Grid1184    User177 Grid1239
```

But i think, is not optimal because i got repeted values (grids and users)

With the previous query my first idea was this query, but i didn't get any result

```
MATCH
  (t:Taxi {name:'Taxi1813'})<-[:ASSIGNED]-(u2:User)-[:DROP_OFF]->
  (g2:Grid)-[:TO*1..2]-(g:Grid)<-[rp:DROP_OFF]-(u:User)-[:ASSIGNED]->
  (t:Taxi {name:'Taxi1813'})
WITH g2, g
MATCH p=shortestPath((g2)-[r:TO]-(g))
WITH p,
REDUCE(totalTime = 0, x IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) | totalTime + x.time) AS totalTime
RETURN totalTime
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid getting duplicates like `user_a`/`user_b` and `user_b`/`user_a`, you could add a `WHERE ID(u) < ID(u2)` to make sure you only get each pair once:

```
MATCH
  (t:Taxi {name:'Taxi1813'})<-[:ASSIGNED]-(u2:User)-[:DROP_OFF]->
  (g2:Grid)-[:TO*1..2]-(g:Grid)<-[rp:DROP_OFF]-(u:User)-[:ASSIGNED]->(t)
WHERE ID(u) < ID(u2)
RETURN u.name, g.name, u2.name, g2.name
```

Depending on your domain, it make make sense to do that for grids instead/as well (e.g. `WHERE ID(g) < ID(g2)`).

Separately, I don't know if it would help or not, but you might want to consider having a label that is something along the lines of `Reservation` or `Pickup` which might have relationships like `-[:MADE_BY]->(:User)`, `-[:FULFILLED_BY]->(:Taxi)`, `-[:DROPPED_OF_AT]->(:Grid)`.

Comment: Thank you @BrianUnderwood, I tried your suggestion. First with the User condition ID(u)<ID(u2), i still have duplicates User177-Grid1239-User179-Grid1184 and User177-Grid1239-User179-Grid1184, then I added the Grid condition ID(g)<ID(g2), but i just have one result User177-Grid1239 User183-Grid1347

Comment: and yes, once you suggested me adding new labels, I really would like to,but the problem is that we are going to merge two algorithms, and the other student already defined the labels and developed one algorithm. So is not possible to make the changes now :( because we are out of time. Thank you for your suggestions, I hope we don't have problems later on

Comment: For what it's worth, a node can have multiple labels. So, it might have been possible to merge the two algorithms.

Comment: I tried this, and it seems it works... I added a DISTINCT  MATCH (t:Taxi {name:'Taxi1813'})<-[:ASSIGNED]-(u2:User)-[:DROP_OFF]-> (g2:Grid)-[r:TO*1..2]-(g:Grid)<-[rp:DROP_OFF]-(u:User)-[:ASSIGNED]->(t) WHERE ID(u2) < ID(u) WITH DISTINCT u2, g2, u, g MATCH p=shortestPath((g2:Grid)-[r:TO*1..2]-(g:Grid)) WITH u2, u, p, REDUCE(totalTime = 0, x IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) | totalTime + x.time) AS totalTime WHERE totalTime <= 4 RETURN totalTime, u2, u Is that okay? Thank you